# Would the complement of the set of positive numbers union the set of negative numbers be an empty set or 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics

NOT(Positive numbers union negative numbers)=?
0 or empty set if the universe of discourse is all integers?

Comment: Neither.  It's the set containing $0.$

Answer (score 3):

The union of positives and negatives do not include $0$ because $0$ is neither positive, nor negative.

Thus the complement of the union is the set {$0$}.

Answer (score 0):

Zero is neither a positive nor a negative number. So $Z^+$ U $Z^-$ does not include zero which in result makes it's negation equals to ${0}$.
Note that whenever we need to make emphasis that 0 belongs to a set it's more preferred to say Non-negative instead of positive because the non-negativity of 0 is clearer to see compared to its non-positivity.